# Calling functions on data types in haskell

Tags: haskell

How am I supposed to call this stuff from main?

```
data Poly' = Lit Integer |
             Add Poly' Poly' |
             Sub Poly' Poly'

eval::Poly'->Integer
eval (Lit n)     = n
eval (Add p1 p2) = (eval p1) + (eval p2)
eval (Sub p1 p2) = (eval p1) - (eval p2)
```

I am trying this, but it doesn't work:

```
main = do
print(eval Add(2 3))
```

Comment: What about it doesn't work?  What kind of error messages are you getting?

Comment: Let's start from the inside out: The expression `2 3` doesn't make sense.

Comment: For all those who down-voted, all of the code above is my very own code. just as fyi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure your problem is that Add takes two Poly's unfortunately you are calling it with ints not Poly's. Lit 2 is a Poly', 2 is an int.

Answer (score 6):

Try `main = print . eval $ Add (Lit 2) (Lit 3)`

Your use of parens suggests you don't quite understand haskell function application. You should almost never write `a(b c)` because its really `a (b c)`, that is, `a $ b c` whereas the former looks more like C function application, which it is most certainly not.

Comment: @Chris Martin yes it does